# from array output date from monday to friday

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to output below array in a week base format from Monday to friday like:

OUTPUT:

Mi 06.01. - Fr 08.01.

Mo 11.01. - Fr 15.01.

Any suggestions how i can exclude the weekdays in between?

```
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Mi 06.01."
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Do 07.01."
  [2]=>
  string(9) "Fr 08.01."
  [3]=>
  string(9) "Mo 11.01."
  [4]=>
  string(9) "Di 12.01."
  [5]=>
  string(9) "Mi 13.01."
  [6]=>
  string(9) "Do 14.01."
  [7]=>
  string(9) "Fr 15.01."
  [8]=>
  string(9) "Mo 18.01."
  [9]=>
  string(9) "Di 19.01."
  [10]=>
  string(9) "Mi 20.01."
  [11]=>
  string(9) "Do 21.01."
  [12]=>
  string(9) "Fr 22.01."
  [13]=>
  string(9) "Mo 25.01."
  [14]=>
  string(9) "Di 26.01."
  [15]=>
  string(9) "Mi 27.01."
  [16]=>
  string(9) "Do 28.01."
  [17]=>
  string(9) "Fr 29.01."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a loop, strip out the unwanted items, and build a new array .. Probably the easiest like so ..

```
<?php
$old_array = array();

$old_array[0] = "Mi 06.01.";
$old_array[1] = "Do 06.01.";
$old_array[2] = "Fr 06.01.";
$old_array[3] = "Mi 06.01.";
$old_array[4] = "Mo 06.01.";




$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $item){
    if (strpos($item, 'Mo') !== false || // Checks if $item conains "Mo" 
        strpos($item, 'Mi') !== false) { // Checks if $item conains "Mi" 
        // push to new array
        array_push($new_array ,$item);
    }
}
print_r($new_array);
```

`$new_array` output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mi 06.01.
    [1] => Mi 06.01.
    [2] => Mo 06.01.
)
```

It will be slightly labor intensive -- But really it's the easiest way to accomplish it.  To get your "range" you can create a function with a "start" and "end" and compare that way, and `return` your range as a string or array etc etc ..

```
<?php
$old_array = array();

$old_array[0]= "Mi 06.01.";
$old_array[1]= "Do 07.01.";
$old_array[2]= "Fr 08.01.";
$old_array[3]= "Mo 11.01.";
$old_array[4]= "Di 12.01.";
$old_array[5]= "Mi 13.01.";
$old_array[6]= "Do 14.01.";
$old_array[7]= "Fr 15.01.";
$old_array[8]= "Mo 18.01.";
$old_array[9]= "Di 19.01.";
$old_array[10]= "Mi 20.01.";
$old_array[11]= "Do 21.01.";
$old_array[12]= "Fr 22.01.";
$old_array[13]= "Mo 25.01.";
$old_array[14]= "Di 26.01.";
$old_array[15]= "Mi 27.01.";
$old_array[16]= "Do 28.01.";
$old_array[17]= "Fr 29.01.";


$start_day = "Mi 06.01.";
$end_day = "Fr 08.01.";

$new_array = makeNewArray($old_array, $start_day, $end_day);
print_r( $new_array );



function makeNewArray($old_array, $start_day, $end_day){
    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($old_array as $item){
        if ($start_day == $item){
            $new_array['start'] = $item;
        }
        if ($end_day == $item){
            $new_array['end'] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [start] => Mi 06.01.
    [end] => Fr 08.01.
)
Start = Mi 06.01.
End = Fr 08.01.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to automatically create the range strings. This should do it. There's not much info provided, so I'm making some assumptions, e.g. the dates are already in the correct order.

Output:

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(21) "Mi 06.01. - Fr 08.01."
[1]=>
string(21) "Mo 11.01. - Fr 15.01."
[2]=>
string(21) "Mo 18.01. - Fr 22.01."
[3]=>
string(21) "Mo 25.01. - Fr 29.01."
}
```

Explanations inline:

```
$date_ranges = [];
$current_week_string = false;

foreach ($dates as $date) {

    // unsure how to easily parse the german day abbreviations so i'll ignore them
    // with ?? and use the dates instead
    $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('?? d.m.', $date);

    // year-week e.g. 2021-01, to keep track of when we change to the next week
    $week_string = $datetime->format('Y-W');

    // still in the same week as the previous date. skip for now
    if ($current_week_string == $week_string) {
        $previous_date = $date;
        continue;
    }

    // create the date range (unless this is the first iteration)
    if ($current_week_string !== false) {
        $date_ranges[] = $start_of_week . ' - ' . $previous_date;
    }

    // reset everything for the next loop
    $start_of_week = $date;
    $current_week_string = $week_string;
    $previous_date = $date;
}

// create the range for the final date
$date_ranges[] = $start_of_week . ' - ' . $date;

var_dump($date_ranges);
```